# BaseMAP Gallery Popup for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, arcgis, image-gallery

I am using **ARCGIS** library for GIS features, I wants to achieve basemap gallery like the one show in below picture.

[image]

how can I achieve above gallery, I tried to search sample code but did not get anything like shown in above picture.....

if possible if any one has done can give me the link to refer sample code...will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code for popup `galary` in `IPad`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var popController:UIPopoverPresentationController!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func btn_action(sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum) {

            self.imagePicker.delegate = self
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
            self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            popController = imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!
            popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up
            popController.delegate = self
            popController.sourceView = self.view
            let contentSize : CGSize = CGSizeMake(500,400)
            self.imagePicker.preferredContentSize = contentSize
            popController.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
            popController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(sender.frame.origin.x + sender.bounds.width/2-5, sender.frame.origin.y+sender.bounds.size.height/2, 10, 10)
        }
    }

    internal override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
    }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {

    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
    {
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension UIImagePickerController
{
    public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
    }
}
```